# Format Specifier for long double in c

Tags: c

I'm using **Windows 8.1 64 bit**.

IDE: **Eclipse Luna(4.4.0)**.

and using **MinGW v4.9.1**

I typed this program in eclipse but it is showing showing zeroes in long double. i tried both %llf and %Lf and also tried type casting but nothing worked for me.

```
1.   int main(void) {  
2.   float floatNumber;
3.   double doubleNumber;
4.   long double longDoubleNumber;
5.
6.   // Size of floating point types
7.   printf("Storage size for unsigned float : %lu  bytes \n", sizeof(float));
8.   printf("Storage size for double :         %lu  bytes \n", sizeof(double));
9.   printf("Storage size for long double :   %lu  bytes \n", sizeof(long double));
10.
11.  floatNumber = 2.0/3.0;
12.  doubleNumber = 2.0/3.0;
13.  longDoubleNumber = 2.0/3.0;
14.
15.  puts("\nCompare precision at 4 decimal points:");
16.  printf("floatNumber      = %1.4f\n", floatNumber);
17.  printf("doubleNumber     = %1.4lf\n", doubleNumber);
18.  printf("longDoubleNumber = %1.4Lf\n", longDoubleNumber);
19.
20.  puts("\nCompare precision at 10 decimal points:");
21.  printf("floatNumber      = %1.10f\n", floatNumber);
22.  printf("doubleNumber     = %1.10lf\n", doubleNumber);
23.  printf("longDoubleNumber = %1.10Lf\n", longDoubleNumber);
24.
25.  puts("\nCompare precision at 30 decimal points:");
26.  printf("floatNumber      = %1.30f\n", floatNumber);
27.  printf("doubleNumber     = %1.50lf\n", doubleNumber);
28.  printf("longDoubleNumber = %1.50Lf\n", longDoubleNumber);
29.  return 0;
30.  }
```

here's the output:-

```
Floating point type usage in C:
Storage size for unsigned float : 4  bytes 
Storage size for double :         8  bytes 
Storage size for long double :   16  bytes 

Compare precision at 4 decimal points:
floatNumber      = 0.6667
doubleNumber     = 0.6667
longDoubleNumber = 0.0000

Compare precision at 10 decimal points:
floatNumber      = 0.6666666865
doubleNumber     = 0.6666666667
longDoubleNumber = 0.0000000000

Compare precision at 30 decimal points:
floatNumber      = 0.666666686534881590000000000000
doubleNumber     = 0.66666666666666663000000000000000000000000000000000
longDoubleNumber = 0.00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

And when i tried this:

```
printf("Storage size for unsigned float : %zu  bytes \n", sizeof floatNumber);
printf("Storage size for double :         %zu  bytes \n", sizeof doubleNumber);
printf("Storage size for long double :   %zu  bytes \n", sizeof longDoubleNumber);
```

the output is:

```
Floating point type usage in C:
Storage size for unsigned float : zu  bytes 
Storage size for double :         zu  bytes 
Storage size for long double :   zu  bytes
```

everything else is same as above.

The List of Warnings shown by Eclipse are:-

```
line 7,8,9,18,23,28:- too many arguments for format [-Wformat-extra-args]
line 18,23,28:- unknown conversion type character 'L' in format [-Wformat=]
line 7,8,9:- format '%lu' expects argument of type 'long unsigned int', but argument
             2 has type 'long long unsigned int' [-Wformat=]

{if i use %zu instead of %lu}
line 7,8,9:- unknown conversion type character 'z' in format [-Wformat=]
```

What is the format specifier for long double?

Comment: You'd be wise to put your toolchain and platform names and versions in this question, please. And your last printf specifier is wrong. That should be `%1.50Lg`. [See it live](http://ideone.com/kXYpFD).

Comment: Are you using Windows?

Comment: With the use of `"%zu"` instead of `"%lu"` for the `sizeof(...)` arguments and the use of `"%1.50Lf"` instead of `"%1.50g"` for the last `printf`, I get expected results.

Comment: ... and - provided you use gcc - don't forget to specify -Wformat (or similar, see docs). Then you'll get compiler warnings if you're using unsuitable format specifiers.

Comment: Yes. I'm using Windows. and  eclipse gives this warning : Multiple markers at this line - unknown conversion type character 'L' in format [- Wformat=]

Comment: It looks like your C library isn't C99 (`%zu` and `%Lf` aren't part of C89 -- nor is `%lf`, btw, but this often works with C89 libcs). This is a common issue on Windows, MinGW has its own fixed `printf` versions (maybe only newer versions do), iirc.

Comment: wrt `%f`/`%lf`, in C99, they both are equivalent and expect a `double`. Default argument promotions on the variadic arguments converts `float` to `double`.

Comment: @mafso didn't worked :(

Answer (score 1):

`size_t` is the type `sizeof()` returns so use `zu` format specifier. Using wrong format specifier leads to undefined behavior.

```
printf("Storage size for unsigned float : %zu  bytes \n", sizeof(float));
```

Note: `%zd` is for signed ssize_t

Comment: `%zu` is for `size_t`, `%zd` is for `ssize_t`

Comment: unknown conversion type character 'z' in format [-Wformat=]

Comment: Is there any problem with my IDE(Eclipse)?

Comment: @Akshay I don't know :) :(

Comment: @cremno Found nothing to support that size of  `ssize_t` is defined as the _same size_ as `size_t`.`'z'` is defined for `size_t`.   Thus "`%zd` is for `ssize_t`" appears to be anecdotal and not definitive.  With various *nix types with an indefinite relationship to standard types, casting to a wide type is fairly safe.  e.g.  `printf("%jd", (intmax_t) ssize_t_var)`

Comment: @chux: I think this could be an interesting question. You're right, it is mostly anecdotal, except the [Linux man pages](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/printf.3.html) explicitly say so. The *BSD ones doesn't, but when reading the source code (Free/NetBSD only bug-free since [2009](https://bugs.freebsd.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=131880)), commits and changelogs it looks like functions and developers are okay with it. However the authoritative POSIX standards doesn't seem to guarantee that ssize_t is the corresponding signed integer type. I guess the misunderstanding is due to its name.